# A Queue that ensure uniqueness of the elements?

Tags: java, collections, queue, guava, unique-constraint

I'm looking for a implementation of java.util.Queue or something in the Google collection who behave like a Queue, but also ensure that each element of the queue is unique. (all further insertion will have no effect)

It's that possible, or will I have to do it by hand?

For now I'm using a Queue, with a LinkedList implementation, and I check the uniqueness before insertion. ( I use a side Map for doing this, add / remove element from the side map before / after the queu ). I don't like it too much.

Any input is welcome. If it's not in the java.util package, then maybe it's a bad idea?

Comment: TreeSet. It's a sorted Set, and Set implies "no duplicate elements".

Comment: I don't think TreeSet preserves the queueing order.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

How about a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)? Its iterator preserves insertion order, but because it's a `Set`, its elements are unique.

As its documentation says,

> Note that insertion order is *not* affected if an element is *re-inserted* into the set.

In order to efficiently remove elements from the head of this "queue", go through its iterator:

```
Iterator<?> i = queue.iterator();
...
Object next = i.next();
i.remove();
```

Comment: The problem is it doesn't implement Queue and hence there's no way to remove elements in FIFO order.

Comment: @Adamski - removing elements in FIFO order is simple. See my update.

Comment: Easy enough to augment LinkedHashSet to add push and pop. Not efficient, but naive pop could be:

Iterator<T> it = iterator();
T result = it.next();
it.remove();
return result;

Comment: Nice. Sorry, i miss the LinkedHashSet while scanning the collection. 

What do you think of implementing java.util.Queue with a home made class, and with a backend LinkedHashSet ?

Comment: ... although creating an iterator for each removal operation seems pretty ugly.

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the queue. If you are going to add a bunch of objects and then remove a bunch of objects---probably within a single thread---using the `Iterator` is perfectly natural, and I'd probably just reference it as a `Collection`. If you really need a `BlockingQueue` to communicate between threads, this isn't the right approach.

Comment: It also depends on whether you're going to add to the end of the queue while processing an element. Adding to a Queue during processing of elements removed from that Queue is well-defined behavior, but with an Iterator, you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException because the built-in Java Collections assume it's a threading issue, not someone abusing the Collection and its Iterator as if the two combined were a Queue implementation.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Concurrent modification issues can be worked around by only using the iterator for a single retrieval:  `Object next = queue.iterator.next();  queue.remove(next);`.  But having to create a new iterator for each retrieval might not be great for efficiency.

Answer (score 26):

This doesn't exist as far as I know but would be fairly simple to implement using a `LinkedList` in conjunction with a `Set`:

```
/**
 * Thread unsafe implementation of UniqueQueue.
 */
public class UniqueQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {
  private final Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();
  private final Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

  public boolean add(T t) {
    // Only add element to queue if the set does not contain the specified element.
    if (set.add(t)) {
      queue.add(t);
    }

    return true; // Must always return true as per API def.
  }

  public T remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
    T ret = queue.remove();
    set.remove(ret);
    return ret;
  }

  // TODO: Implement other Queue methods.
}
```

Comment: Although this works, there is a huge performance cosr to it. I dont think you need both a set and a linkedlist

Comment: that's what tvanfosson is proposing as well, and very close of what i already have. I'm just curious about a more standard way.

Comment: @Cshah: Why do you think there's a huge cost performance?  Assuming your hash algorithm is fast and efficient, set insert and removal operations will approximate to O(1), which is much faster than scanning the LinkedList each time: O(n).

Comment: @adamki: The approach by tvanfosson is much cleaner. In your case, each element is added to both the queue(linked list) and the set (to ensure uniqueness). I believe that just a hashset should suffice

Comment: @Cshah: What are you talking about?!  tvanfosson's approach is *the same* as mine - He just hasn't provided example code.  Also, erickson's approach of using a LinkedHashSet is essentially *the same*, as internally LinkedHashSet contains a linked list.  Using "just a hashset" will not provide queue-like behaviour.

Comment: Why not just use java.util.TreeSet?

Comment: A TreeSet does not support FIFO access: Elements will be inserted according to their natural ordering (or the ordering of the supplied Comparator) rather thn at the end of the "queue".  Granted you could provide a Comparator to mimic FIFO-like behavior but this is an ugly hack IMHO that offers no real benefit.

Comment: If you replace the LinkedList with ArrayDeque you will get better performance (x2) for polling than the LinkedHashSet. Here's a blog post comparing the implementations: http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2013/03/merging-queue-arraydeque-and-suzie-q.html

Comment: About the `return true` in `add`. Isn't there a conflict between the contract of `Collection#add` and `Queue#add`? This collection is supposed to guarantee the uniqueness so it should return `false` according to the `Collection` javadoc. At the same time, the `Queue` javadoc explicitly mentions the method as returning `true` or throwing an exception.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add(E)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)
Not sure which of these two contracts should be followed in this case.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz: +1 That's a really good point.  My first thought was that given the class implements Queue (and only uses Set internally) it should follow the Queue contract.  However, the contract states that an IllegalStateException should only be thrown if the capacity is exceeded.  In this case it's not even that; I'm simply ignoring the add attempt for non-unique elements.  Given this, I wonder if in fact the class should implement neither Queue, nor Set.

Comment: The purpose being to implement a queue handling uniqueness, the queue#add should definitely return the return value of the set#add because you may want to know, when calling the method, whether the element was already in there or not. Additionnally, this class should implement the remaining Queue methods like element(), offer() poll(), peek(). Except that, this class definitely meet the needs

Comment: What if thread safety was a requirement?

Answer (score 6):

I'd be tempted to maintain a [HashSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) containing a key that uniquely identifies the items in the queue side-by-side with it.  Then just check the HashSet to see if the item is in the queue before adding it.  When you remove an item from the Queue, simply remove the key from the HashSet as well.

Comment: This seems like the way to go when dealing with a scenario like this question here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447461/in-treeset-sorting-uniqueness-of-custom-objects-based-on-different-properties/

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete Adamski's answer:

```
/**
 * A queue that keeps each element only once. 
 * If you try to add an element that already exists - nothing will happen.
 * 
 * @author Adamski http://stackoverflow.com/a/2319156/827927
 * @NotThreadSafe
 */
public class UniqueQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {

private final Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();
private final Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

@Override public boolean add(T t) {
    // Only add element to queue if the set does not contain the specified element.
    if (set.add(t))
        queue.add(t);
    return true; // Must always return true as per API def.
}

@Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> arg0) {
    boolean ret = false;
    for (T t: arg0)
        if (set.add(t)) {
            queue.add(t);
            ret = true;
        }
    return ret;
}

@Override public T remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
    T ret = queue.remove();
    set.remove(ret);
    return ret;
}

@Override public boolean remove(Object arg0) {
    boolean ret = queue.remove(arg0);
    set.remove(arg0);
    return ret;
}

@Override public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
    boolean ret = queue.removeAll(arg0);
    set.removeAll(arg0);
    return ret;
}

@Override public void clear() {
    set.clear();
    queue.clear();
}

@Override public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
    return set.contains(arg0);
}

@Override public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
    return set.containsAll(arg0);
}

@Override public boolean isEmpty() {
    return set.isEmpty();
}

@Override public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return queue.iterator();
}

@Override public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override public int size() {
    return queue.size();
}

@Override public Object[] toArray() {
    return queue.toArray();
}

@Override public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0) {
    return queue.toArray(arg0);
}

@Override public T element() {
    return queue.element();
}

@Override public boolean offer(T e) {
    return queue.offer(e);
}

@Override public T peek() {
    return queue.peek();
}

@Override public T poll() {
    return queue.poll();
}
}
```

Comment: If you replace the LinkedList with ArrayDeque you will get better performance (x2) for polling than the LinkedHashSet, and should beat your implementation as well. Here's a blog post comparing the implementations: http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2013/03/merging-queue-arraydeque-and-suzie-q.html

Comment: The queue methods are not in sync with the set methods, e.g. poll() should also remove the element from the set, otherwise it can happen that you ask !isEmpty() somewhere in the code, and then when you call poll() it results in a NPE.

Answer (score 4):

Checking uniqueness of course has a cost (either in space or time).  Seems like it might be interesting to work from something like a PriorityQueue which will maintain a heap sorted by Comparator of the elements.  You might be able to leverage that to more efficiently (O(log n)) check existence without maintaining a side map.

If you do want to wrap a Queue with a uniqueness checker, I would strongly recommend using the Google Collections [ForwardingQueue](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingQueue.html) to build such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't exist. Since I needed such a Queue I have developed a Blocking Queue backed by a set, inspired by *java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue*.

You can find it here :

https://github.com/bvanalderweireldt/concurrent-unique-queue

Example :

```
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentSetBlockingQueue<>(1);
queue.offer(new Integer(1)); //True
queue.offer(new Integer(1)); //False
```

You can use it with Maven :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hybhub</groupId>
  <artifactId>concurrent-util</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late to answer but I ended up solving a similar problem using an ArrayDeque and overriding the add method that I needed.

```
    Deque<Long> myQueue = new ArrayDeque<Long>() {
        @Override
        public boolean add(Long e) { return !this.contains(e) && super.add(e);}
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. There is no existing straightforward solution. I'll dig up some code I wrote a while back that attempted to do this, and come back and edit this answer.

**EDIT:** I'm back. Truly, if you don't need concurrency, you are better off maintaining a Queue and Set separately. For what I was doing, concurrency was a goal, but the best solution I could come up with given that constraint was problematic; basically, since it used a ConcurrentHashMap, the more you were removing the "head" element from the queue (a basic thing to do with a queue), the more unbalanced the hash table would become over time. I can still share this code with you, but I doubt you really want it.

**EDIT:** For the case where concurrency is required I gave this answer:
[Concurrent Set Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120495/concurrent-set-queue/3121453#3121453)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the add method when initializing your queue variable.

```
Queue<T> queue = new PriorityQueue<>() {
  @Override
  public boolean add(T t) {
    return !this.contains(t) && super.add(t);
  }
};
```

... or you can implement the Queue interface.

Answer (score 0):

I used `LinkedHashSet` for that:

```
public class UniqueQueue<T> {

    private final LinkedHashSet<T> queue;

    public UniqueQueue() {
        queue = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    public void enqueue(T item) {
        synchronized (UniqueQueue.class) {
            queue.add(item);
        }
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        synchronized (UniqueQueue.class) {
            Iterator<T> i = queue.iterator();

            T next = i.next();
            i.remove();

            return next;
        }
    }
}
```