# Any efficient BlockingQueue implementations that allow combining of entries?

Tags: java, blockingqueue, merging-data

Are there any efficient (without synchronize everything) implementations of java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue that allow combining of entries?

By combining I mean to merge incoming item with existing "equal" entry on the queue (if there is one), otherwise item is added at the end as usual.

Comment: So, you mean a kind of Queue that behaves like a Set in that it doesn't allow duplicate elements?

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer out: [Concurrent Set Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120495/concurrent-set-queue). It might be a duplicate of your question if all that you mean by merging is ignoring elements that are equal to something that's already on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

`BlockingQueue` sports a `contains` method. Feel free to use it, but don't forget to synchronize. `contains` is O(n) f.x. in `LinkedBlockingDeque`, so you may try a more efficient approach with a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see combining events if timestamp and source are two of its attributes.  Unless the same user sent two events within a nanosecond or less of each other, I don't believe they can be considered equal and should not be combined.