# java.util.Queue implementation that provides equal elements at most once

Tags: java

I'm looking for a `java.util.Queue` implementation that queues up equal elements at most once.

E.g., such a `specialQueue` should behave like so:

```
E e1;
E e2;
E e3;
//...
assertThat( e1, is(e2) );
assertThat( e1, is(not(e3)) );

Queue<E> specialQueue;
//...
specialQueue.offer(e1);
specialQueue.offer(e2);
specialQueue.offer(e3);


assertThat( specialQueue.poll(), is(e1) );
assertThat( specialQueue.poll(), is(e3) );
assertThat( specialQueue.poll(), is(null) );
// FIFO semantics are not relevant to the question

specialQueue.offer(e3)
assertThat( specialQueue.poll(), is(null) );
```

I came up with an implementation that manages an internal `Set<E> alreadySeenElements`, and guards against adding elements to a delegate queue by checking against that set. I was wondering if there already exists a "battle-tested" implementation.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319086/a-queue-that-ensure-uniqueness-of-the-elements

Comment: @Sneh, thank you for making me aware of the other question, which indeed is very close to mine. The answers over there seem to be more focused on uniqueness of an element during that elements entry within the queue, not on uniqueness of an element during the queue lifetime.

Comment: I think uniqueness requirement is breaking Queue contract. E.g. Queue.add must return true or throw IllegalStateException if the element cannot be added due to capacity restrictions.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev, good point. But is a uniqueness constraint in violation to a capacity constraint? Also, the Java Class Library includes `Queue` subclasses such as `java.util.ArrayDeque` that explicitly remove the capacity restriction.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a violation. Of course what you want is quite legal, but dont call it a Queue, dont implement Queue. This is my point

Comment: If `FIFO semantics are not relevant`  then how it could be called a queue?

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenters suggest, you're more describing a special kind of `Set` than a `Queue`. From what I understand, your requirements are:

- Insertion-order iteration
- Each element in the collection is unique (non-equal)
- Previously seen elements can *never* be re-added

The first two requirements are well served by a `LinkedHashSet`, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2319086/113632) suggests. The last requirement is much stranger, and requires some sort of internal store of previously seen values.  Something like:

```
public class SeenOnceLinkedHashSet<E> implements Set<E> {
  private LinkedHashSet<E> data;
  private HashSet<E> seen;

  public boolean add(E e) {
    boolean newValue = seen.add(e);
    if (newValue) {
      return data.add(e);
    }

  // and so on in other methods
}
```

Notice that this class has unbounded internal memory. You could easily cause an out-of-memory issue using this class in a way other `Set`s would handle without problem. If you require some notion of "has ever been added" this is unavoidable. You could use something more elegant like a [`BloomFilter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html), but that would introduce false positives.

Personally, I would re-examine your requirements. Any sort of unbounded-space data structure is almost certainly a code smell. Could you, for instance, use a wrapper class that provides a more helpful definition of `.equals()`? Or add additional safety checks at object construction time so bad objects aren't constructed in the first place?