# Java data structure with push/pop and no duplicates?

Tags: java, data-structures, set, queue

I'm looking for a queue-type data structure in Java (preferably in the standard libs) which has the following properties:

- I can add an element to the structure (push)
- I can remove an arbitrary element from the structure *without specifying which element*, like the `remove()` operation of a queue. Obviously this fails if the structure is empty.
- If I add an element to the structure that is already in it, it is not added twice.

Preserving the order of insertion/deletion isn't terribly important.

`Set` structures have the no duplicates, but don't have the `pop` operation, and `Queue` structures don't guarantee no duplicates. Does something fitting my needs exist?

In the interests of avoiding the XY problem, I'm doing a worklist algorithm: nodes that need updating are added to the set, so I want to easily pop the next node that needs updating, and add nodes that need updating without getting a bunch of duplicates if they're already in the worklist.

Comment: looks like the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319086/a-queue-that-ensure-uniqueness-of-the-elements

Comment: @Golionko Similar. This question doesn't have ordering requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LinkedHashSet`, and implement `pop` as

```
Iterator<E> iterator = set.iterator();
E result = iterator.next();
iterator.remove();
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean`iterator.next();` and `iterator.remove();` ?

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set's iterator to remove a single element. The ordering will depend on the set implementation.

```
static <T> T remove(Set<T> set) {
    Iterator<T> iter = set.iterator();
    T element = iter.next();
    iter.remove();
    return element;
}
```