# On-the-fly comparator that works correctly with ConcurrentSkipListSet

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, happens-before, concurrentskiplistmap

I'm trying to use

`queue = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Task>(Comparators.comparing(Task::priority))`

as a concurrent priority queue with unique elements (see a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2319086/9398584)), but I need to change the priority of tasks from time to time.

Clearly to change the priority of elements *while they're in the set* is to open a can of worms; fortunately, I only need to change their priority after removing them from `queue`, and before resubmitting them. More precisely, I use `pollFirst()` to pop an element from the `queue`, which I may need to resubmit after updating its priority (with a lower priority).

If this was a serial implementation, there should be no problem with changing the priority of elements while they're outside of the set.

**What's a thread-safe way of doing this update with concurrent access?**
Is it enough to guarantee that

`task = queue.pollFirst()` happens before `task.priorityUpdate()`, happens before `queue.add(task)`?

Comment: It sounds like enough to me — I haven’t seen any flaw. Obviously another thread may take out and use an element that you had decided to down-prioritize but had not yet come around to (but I don’t think this was what you were asking).

Comment: Your title seems to not fit your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

All concurrent collections establish happen-before relationships between element put and element get.

The problem would be if you need to change priority while they are in the queue, and you take them out and put them back in because that is the only way; then, a concurrent thread may put the same element in the meantime and then you would have lost your modification. In that case, further synchronization would be required.

But if you are taking elements out, changing their priority and only then evaluating whether they should be put back in, happen-before guarantees of concurrent collections are enough to ensure correctness, and you need do nothing else.

From `add()` to `pollFirst()` there is a happens-before relationship, so the object created in the thread calling `add()` is visible to the thread calling `pollFirst()`.

From `pollFirst()` to `add()` there is not. However, if you change the priority and then call `add()` from the same thread, no further memory constraints are needed.
If you later call `pollFirst()` from another thread, the happens-before relationship between `add()` and `pollFirst()` will guarantee the updates to the object before calling `add()` are visible.